# facebook links getting info from websites

Tags: javascript, facebook, hyperlink

hi i was wondering how facebook turns their links into information from the sites before and after posting.

and also, how do they get a thumbnail image from the youtube videos? After all this , is it possible to just append the embedded youtube code to the page and start the movie by using youtubes api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting youtube video embed code and thumbnail take a look at http://www.oembed.com/

Answer (score 1):

They have their servers request the URI mentioned by the user. It is HTML, and thus easy to find images in the source.

Using YouTube's API would be a logical approach to solving that problem.